# current_page? URL for dynamic urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have a situation where I am trying to call:

```
%li{class: current_page?("/photos")  && 'current'}
  = link_to "Life Story", legacy_legacy_path(@legacy.slug), :class => "legacy"
```

where the current url (which I'm trying to target looks like):

```
...com/scooby-doo/photos
```

Where 'scooby-doo' in this case, is a dynamic parameter.

Is there any way I can just query the URL for the last part? I.E. `/photos`

Comment: the `current_page?` method is a boolean and returns either `true` or `false`. Could you possible try to explain what you are trying to accomplish further so we can understand exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: specifically, I want to know what parameters to pass to current_page? to target just the /photos part of the url, there is a dynamic parameter that appears also in the url so trying to call `current_page?('/scooby-doo/photos')` will work for this specific page, and none others where the scooby-doo parameter will change

Comment: You should be able to add the `path_name` and it will work for all `:id's`, not just scooby-doo. So if you did a `rake routes`, and told me what this particular `path_name` looks like, I could help further. Prob something like `photo_legacy_path(@legacy)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add the `path_name` and it will work for all `:id's`, not just scooby-doo. So if you did a `rake routes`, and told me what this particular `path_name` looks like, I could help further. Prob something like `current_page?(photo_legacy_path(@legacy))`